# Modify network packets on the fly according to rules

Tags: networking, windows-10, packet-injection

I tried to ask security or networking professionals but my question was rejected as off-topic twice, so this is my last try.

I have Windows 10 machine with 3 gateways and I'd like to route packets from different apps to different gateways according to table of rules.

For instance - all DNS requests must flow through protected VPN channel while Skype traffic must go to the fastest gateway. I know how to do it in Linux but I suspect that for Windows I need some kind of MITM hacking software which can inspect TCP/IP headers (and even application layer headers) and re-write destination IP address (and possibly some other fields).

Is there any solution? I thought to write my own using scapy but it can only change a shadow copy of the packet but not the original. I can't replace target OS it should be Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python: [pydivert - Python binding to windivert driver](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydivert)

C*: [Windows Filtering Platform (WFP)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/packet-modification-examples)